# Dificuldades na Criação de Rotas e Controller Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Criei um CRUD com Modal está funcionando tudo certo mas criei  requisição do formulário exibição de dados, consultas com BD tudo dentro de Rotas, não acho muito legal gostaria de passar essas funcionalidades para o Controller fazer mas não está dando certo está aparecendo o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje o CRUD está assim:

**app\routes.php**

```
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::get('/admin', function () {
    $tasks = Task::all();

    return View::make('admin')->with('tasks',$tasks);
});



Route::get('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::post('/tasks',function(Request $request){
    $task = Task::create($request->all());

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::put('/tasks/{task_id?}',function(Request $request,$task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    $task->task = $request->task;
    $task->description = $request->description;

    $task->save();

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::delete('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::destroy($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});
```

Depois criei desta forma para que o Controller faça o trabalho mas não está dando certo

**app\routes.php**

```
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::controller('/admin', 'TaskController');
```

**controllers\TaskController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getindex()
    {
        $tasks = Task::all();

        return View::make('admin')->with('tasks',$tasks);


    }

    public function getAdd($task_id)
    {
        $task = Task::find($task_id);

        return Response::json($task);
    }

    public function postAdd(Request $request)
    {

        $task = Task::create($request->all());

        return Response::json($task);

    }


    public function getEdit($task_id)
    {
        $task = Task::find($task_id);

        return Response::json($task);
    }

    public function postEdit(Request $request, $task_id)
    {

       // $task = $request->except('_token');

        $task = Task::find($task_id);

        $task->task = $request->task;
        $task->description = $request->description;

        $task->save();

        return Response::json($task);


    }

    public function getDelete($task_id)
    {
        $task = Task::destroy($task_id);

        return Response::json($task);

    }


}
```

Comment: Dei uma olhada no código-fonte do `Laravel` e, se não me engano, `Route::controller` foi depreciado. Pode ser removido em versões futuras.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/98fb934b669c45aad6ca118d4fe29f2bf141d7f6

Answer (score 3):

Para criação do CRUD com controllers, eu sugiro que você use o método `Route::resouce`.

Ele é bem simples, e você apenas precisa ter um controller com os seguintes métodos:

```
 (get) index
 (get) edit
 (post) update
 (get) create
 (post) store
 (delete) destroy
```

Basta utilizar o código abaixo na rota:

```
 Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

Uma boa referência é esse vídeo do [Laracast - em inglês](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/9) que fala sobre o uso desse recurso `resource`.

Comment: Vou dar uma olha obrigado!